# spinnerView is not working in appdelegate

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, progress-bar

Hello Here i am using appdeligate for some specific method like login into the apps and logout from the apps.
Here i have a code 
which is currently doing working great but the problem is when login request send to the server then the spinner view is not working

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    spinnerInitialization();
     email = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("email")\\Getting Email from local storage 
     password = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("password")\\\\Getting Password from local storage
    if ((email == nil) && (password == nil)){

    }
    else if ((email == "") && (password == "")) {

   }
    else {
        loginRequest(email!, password: password!)
    }

    return true

}
```

Here Next is the Login Function

```
    func loginRequest( var email: String,password: String){

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "www.example.com/login")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "email=\(email)&password=\(password)&token=\("ttttttt")"

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.startSpinner()
    }

    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){
        data, response, error in
        if(error != nil){

            let nsError = error! as NSError
            let dialog = UIAlertController(title: "Internal Server Error?", message: nsError.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default){(ACTION) in

                print("Ok Button Action ")
            }

            dialog.addAction(okAction);

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                //Code that presents or dismisses a view controller here
                self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(dialog, animated: true, completion: nil)
            })
        }

        else{
        do {
            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments)

            let status  = json["status"]as? Int
            let message = json["message"]as? String

            if(status == 0){


                let dialog = UIAlertController(title: "Login Unsuccessful?", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

                let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default){(ACTION) in

                    print("Ok Button Action ")
                }

                dialog.addAction(okAction);

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                    self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(dialog, animated: true, completion: nil)

                })


            }
            else
            {
                let newModel = UserDetails()
                let result = json["data"]
                let userId = result!!["id"] as? String
                let companyId = result!!["companyId"] as? String
                let name = result!!["name"] as? String
                let companyName = result!!["companyName"] as? String
                email = (result!!["email"] as? String)!
                let userType = result!!["userType"] as? String

                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(email, forKey: "email")
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(userId, forKey: "userId")
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(companyId, forKey: "companyId")
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(name, forKey: "name")
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(companyName, forKey: "companyName")
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(userType, forKey: "userType")
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(password, forKey: "password")
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("afdg2015", forKey: "token")

                newModel.userId = userId!
                newModel.companyId = companyId!
                newModel.userName = name!
                newModel.companyName = companyName!

                if userType == "0"{
                    newModel.asEmployeer = true
                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("true", forKey: "asEmployeer")
                    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("load", object: nil)
                }
                else {
                    newModel.asEmployeer = false
                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("false", forKey: "asEmployeer")
                    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("load", object: nil)
                }

                self.userDetails.append(newModel)

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

                    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                    var scheduleController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("scheduleHome100")
                    if (newModel.asEmployeer == false){
                    //EmployeeScheduleViewController
                         scheduleController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("EmployeeScheduleViewController")
                    }

                    let drawerViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DrawerViewController")

                    let leftSideNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: drawerViewController)
                    let centerNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: scheduleController)

                    self.centerContainer = MMDrawerController(centerViewController: centerNav, leftDrawerViewController: leftSideNav)
                    self.centerContainer!.openDrawerGestureModeMask = MMOpenDrawerGestureMode.PanningCenterView;
                    self.centerContainer!.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = MMCloseDrawerGestureMode.PanningCenterView;

                    self.window!.rootViewController = self.centerContainer
                    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
                }
            }

        } catch {
            print("error serializing JSON: \(error)")
        }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.stopSpinner()
            })
        }
    }

    task.resume();
}
```

Next to that here is spinners function

```
func startSpinner(){
    print("In startSpinner Function")
    view.addSubview(spinnerView)
}

func stopSpinner(){
    print("In stopSpinner Function")
    let subViews = view.subviews
    for subView in subViews{
        if subView.tag == 1000{
            subView.removeFromSuperview()
        }

    }
}

func spinnerInitialization(){
    print("In spinnerInitialization Function")
    spinnerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0,width: 250,height: 50))
    spinnerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    spinnerView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    let wait = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x:0,y: 0,width: 50,height: 50))
    wait.color = UIColor.whiteColor()
    wait.hidesWhenStopped = false
    wait.startAnimating()
    let text = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:60,y:0,width:200,height: 50))
    text.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    text.text = "Please wait..."
    spinnerView.addSubview(wait)
    spinnerView.addSubview(text)
    spinnerView.center = view.center
    spinnerView.tag = 1000
}
```

**UPDATE**
when i am sending the request from ViewController like as

```
  @IBAction func loginAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    let email = textEmail.text
    let password = textPassword.text
    spinnerInitialization()
    startSpinner()
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.loginRequest(email!, password: password!)
}

func spinnerInitialization(){
    spinnerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0,width: 250,height: 50))
    spinnerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    spinnerView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    let wait = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x:0,y: 0,width: 50,height: 50))
    wait.color = UIColor.whiteColor()
    wait.hidesWhenStopped = false
    wait.startAnimating()
    let text = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:60,y:0,width:200,height: 50))
    text.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    text.text = "Please wait..."
    spinnerView.addSubview(wait)
    spinnerView.addSubview(text)
    spinnerView.center = self.view.center
    spinnerView.tag = 1000
}

func startSpinner(){
    view.addSubview(spinnerView)
}

func stopSpinner(){
    let subViews = view.subviews
    for subView in subViews{
        if subView.tag == 1000{
            subView.removeFromSuperview()
        }

    }
}
```

Then the spinner shows

Please help me to resolve that problem 
Thanks

Comment: Please remove     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) where you have start spinner

Comment: @HiteshSurani No it's not working all three function getting call of spinner but not showing it

Comment: dear can you share code with me.(Remove your private code)

Comment: i did share it all that code same to same i have `ViewController` where i want to show that spinner

Comment: check, if spinner object is created before animating it.
I think, spinner might be nil.

Comment: do one thing Please print(view.descripton)  and print(spinnerView.description) insteade 0f static string such as "In stopSpinner Function and etc".

Comment: @HiteshSurani View is Giving me out put like `<UIView: 0x7f9300c27c30; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x7f9300c27590>>` and spinnerView is giving me Output like `<UIView: 0x7f9300e25050; frame = (-125 -25; 250 50); tag = 1000; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f9300e28070>>` and also please check my updates

Comment: It seems that you are storing your `spinnerView` in a property. If so, you can improve your `stopSpinner()` method to simply `spinnerView.removeFromSuperview()` - it is faster and easier to read, and removes the need to set `tag` on `spinnerView`

Comment: @Losiowaty I did try what you said but even still having problem in that

Comment: I think there is problem to send `spinner view` from `appDelegate class` to `View Controller` means `Login Class`

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `dataTaskWithRequest` which is an **Asynchronous** process. You have to add a completion handler in order for your function to wait till the process is complete like so:

```
    func loginRequest( var email: String,password: String ,complete: (evalSuccess: Bool) -> ()){

///Your code:

     if(status == 0){


                    let dialog = UIAlertController(title: "Login Unsuccessful?", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

                    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default){(ACTION) in

                        print("Ok Button Action ")
                    }

                    dialog.addAction(okAction);

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                        self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(dialog, animated: true, completion: nil)

                    })


                }
                else
                {
                  complete(evalSuccess: True)
                    let newModel..
               ///your code

             }
```

And then call it in the `appDelegate` like:

```
loginRequest(youremail, yourpassword){success in
if success{
//Do something
}

}
```

Comment: Here I did use this method at very first time.
Please check my Update what i am using and where i want to show the spinner View

Comment: You have to call the function like how I've shown you in my answer. See the difference.

Comment: `completion(evalSuccess: true)` giving me `Use of unresolved identifier 'completion'`

Comment: Sorry it is `complete` and not `completion`. Edited my answer. Try it now.

Comment: yes i did that and even still i am getting stuck in that

Comment: Here all there spinner method is called `spinnerInitialization` `startSpinner` and `stopSpinner` but problem is it's not showing view

Comment: Let me get back to you on this one. I am sure it's in the `spinner` methods. Keep trying. I'll help you when I get back.

Comment: Yes Sure i am trying

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115112/discussion-between-dershowitz123-and-apk-apps).